# How to fetch follower names of a profile from Twitter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, twython

I am new to python and Twython and I want to fetch a list of all followers of a user and hence I am using this code

```
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
followers = twitter.get_followers_list(screen_name = "abcd")

for theList in followers:
    id = theList[ 0 ]
    print id
```

But I am getting errors. This may be due to the last 3 line.

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: I am getting something like 

previous_users
users
next_users

Something that the documentation mentions as a cursor but I am not able to print the details

Answer (score 1):

get_followers_list returns json object, you can retrieve the fields from json object using the name of the fields,below is an example for the same.

next_cursor = -1

while(next_cursor):

search = twitter.get_followers_list(screen_name='abcd',cursor=next_cursor)

```
for result in search['users']:
    time_zone =result['time_zone'] if result['time_zone'] != None else "N/A"
    print result["name"].encode('utf-8')+ ' '+time_zone.encode('utf-8')
next_cursor = search["next_cursor"]
```